# use case in where clause sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

what im trying to do is to make a query consider or not a datetime value so i dont have to do this in a stored procedure

```
if @considerDate =1
    begin
        select * from table 
        where dateCol = @date
    end
else
    begin 
        select * from table
    end
```

i would like to do somethink like

```
select * from table
where   dateCol = ( case 
                    when  @date is not null
                    then @date
            )
```

In an single query

Answer (score 19):

you just need to add `END` keyword

```
SELECT * 
FROM    tableName
WHERE   dateCol =   CASE WHEN @considerDate =1
                         THEN @date 
                         ELSE dateCol 
                    END
```

Comment: I was going to ask about the ELSE case.  Good answer.

Answer (score 5):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE dateCol = 
   CASE WHEN @date is not null then @date ELSE dateCol END
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if @considerDate =0
    begin
        -- set the variable to null so the select will return all rows from table
        set @date = null
    end

SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE dateCol = IsNull(@date, dateCol)
```

If you don't want to include the date parameter in your query, set the value to null and in your query you can use a null check to decide if it will apply the filter.